# phpinfo() Expression Web 4

Tags: html, php, microsoft-expression-web

I've installed Microsoft Expression Web 4, installed php 5.3.28, renamed the php.ini-production to php.ini, did display_errors=on, did cgi.force_redirect=0, switched the positions of php_mbstring.dll and php_exif.dll (ran php.exe and it said it could not find php_mbstring.dll), directed expression web to the php-cgi.exe, and forced expression web 4 to boot a server for every test. I run the sample code for php information as follows...

file name - "index.php"

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<title>Untitled 1</title>
</head>

<body>
 <?php
 phpinfo() ;
 ?> 

</body>

</html>
```

I get a blank page (WSOD), and am still looking for a solution.

In short I've been following the instructions given [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/expression/ee662148.aspx).

And followed up with some additional potential fixes with little success.
Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem, did a full reinstall of all products involved.